# Why does `dir` not work with current namespace gotten from "current namespace var" - `*ns*`

Tags: clojure

Or, in other words, why does this not work:

```
user=> (dir (ns-name *ns*))
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval2010 (REPL:1).
class clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Symbol (clojure.lang.PersistentList and clojure.lang.Symbol are in unnamed module of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dir` is a macro that expects an unquoted symbol as its argument.  It should be used like:

```
user=> (clojure.repl/dir clojure.string)
blank?
capitalize
escape
join
lower-case
replace
...
```

When you call it like so:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [clojure.repl :as repl]))

(println (repl/dir (ns-name *ns*)))
```

you are not passing an unquoted symbol (eg `clojure.string`), but rather a list with the symbol `ns-name` as its first element.

As the namespace for `clojure.repl/dir` implies, this command is intended to by typed into a REPL by hand, not used programatically.

---

If you do want to get information programatically, you probably want something more like one of these:

```
(ns-publics 'tst.demo.core)
(ns-publics (ns-name *ns*))
```

either of which works.

Be sure to peruse the [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and this [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).